# MongoDB - Fast Aggregation with grouping and min to more than 20M records

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have 20 million rows similar to this and the field "type1" has the following values 1,2,3,4 or 5

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59d55b0324934c04a7534d30"),
    "name" : "Maria",
    "nights" : 3,
    "price" : 322,
    "type1" : 3,
    "type2" : 4,
    "type3" : 5,
    "type4" : 3,
    "departure" : ObjectId("59d540194cb72658a4511665"),
    "destination" : ObjectId("59d5401e4cb72658a4511666"),
    "refundable" : false,
    "active" : true,
    "date_start" : ISODate("2017-04-18T18:33:14.871Z"),
    "date_end" : ISODate("2017-06-30T12:55:04.164Z"),
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-10-04T22:04:51.127Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-10-04T22:04:51.127Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

and I want to find the min price per type1

I run the following aggregation but it is very slow

```
db.fakers.aggregate(
[
 {
   $group:
     {
       _id: "$type1",
       minPrice: { $min: "$price" }
     }
 }
]
)
```

I have also create the following index

```
db.fakers.createIndex( { type1: 1, price: -1 } )
```

Any suggestions? It makes ~20sec to execute

Comment: Indexes won't have any effect on purely a `$group` as it's simply reduced to "raw number crunching" at this point. You would possibly get better performance with `.aggregate([{ "$sort": { "type1": 1, "price": -1 } },{ "$group": { "_id": "$type1", "minPrice": { "$first": "$price" } } }])` where an index **can** have an effect. But really the "bulk" of performance here simply comes down to hardware and possible distributed configuration of sharding to "spread the load".

Comment: so.... with a cluster and sharding you says that the performance will be much better. right?

Comment: Faster cars usually perform better than slower ones yes. What I'm telling you is you don't get something "for free". If you have a lot of data, then you actually need something capable of dealing with your expected response times. Also noting that the query adjustment I gave you should show a marked improvement by itself. But if you expect "sub-second" from 20M results. Then you'd *"Better get a bigger boat!"*